# Where to place Application bundles?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.5

I have an application written with Symfony and want to merge some small bundles as part of that app.

Regarding the quick Symfony2 bundle tour from Sonata, I need an ApplicationBundle.

> quick Symfony2 bundle tour:
>
> - There are two types of bundles:
>
>   - Application Bundle (AB),
>   - Vendor Bundle (VB), that should not be modified inside a project.
> - The AB directory is where developers implement the project requirements,
> - An AB can overwrite almost everything from a VB, example: you can redefine a VB template at the AB level.

([Source](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/easy-extends/master/doc/reference/why.html))

Symfony documentation says about architecture:

> The directory structure of a Symfony application is rather flexible,
>   but the recommended structure is as follows:
>
> - app/: the application configuration;
> - src/: the project's PHP code;
> - vendor/: the third-party dependencies;
> - web/: the web root directory

([Source](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_architecture.html))

But where shall I place it?

There are two possibilities:

- app/Application (Sonata EasyExtends places ApplicationBundles here)
- src

But what is the right one?
And why are there two possibilities?

The Symfony documentation doesn't cover ApplicationBundle.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: You should place your application and its bundles within the src folder. So i.e. src > YourApplication > YourFunctionalityBundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation say that :

- Application Bundles (**in 2 words, this is important**) are stored in `src/` directory.
- Vendor Bundles are stored in `vendor/`directory (and came from your `composer.json` dependencies).

You can (and should) create many bundles for you application.

Comment: In this case, what is the sense of **app/Application**?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can have bundles in the `app` directory. I can't even see why I whould store a bundle here instead of `vendor`.

Comment: There is no sense to app/Application.  Your configuration (AppKernel, config.yml etc) goes under app.  Any actual code ends up under src.